# SIMD algorithm to check of if an integer block is "consecutive."

Tags: rust, simd, avx, avx512

How to you check if an aligned chunk of 16 `u32`'s is consecutive (and increasing)?

For example: `[100, 101, 102, ..., 115]` is.
And, `[100, 99, 3 ...]` is not.

I'm on AVX512f. This is what I have so far:

Algo A:

```
* predefine DECREASE_U32, a u32x16 of [15,14,13,...0]
* let a = input + DECREASE_32 // wrapping is OK
* compare a to u32x16::splat(first_item(a))
* Return whether all true
```

Alterative (Algo B)

```
* let b = copy of A
* permute the elements of b by one position
* let b = a-b
* Is b all 1's (except for 1st position)
```

I'm doing this in Rust with the `packed_simd` crate, but any language/pseudocode` is fine. (I wish there was a SIMD operation to subtract adjacent items.)

Comment: The approach of "Don't use SIMD, write compiler-friendly code" [doesn't seem to work](https://godbolt.org/z/sbnTE96he) in this case. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your first idea is probably best if done inside a loop that can amortize the cost of loading a vector constant.  AVX-512 can do that efficiently.

Either with a vector load and then separately broadcast the low element with `vpbroadcastd`, or with a vector load and a broadcast-load.  e.g. `vpaddd zmm16, zmm31, [rdi]{1to16}` / `vpcmpeqd k1, zmm16, [rdi]`.

Hmm, but then checking for all elements being true, I guess perhaps `kaddw` with a constant `1` and check that the low 16 bits are zero with `kortest`?  Or just `kmov` to an integer register for a compare against `0xffff` like we'd do with SSE/AVX `pmovmskb`.  I tried that, and clang had a better idea: compare for not-equal, and check that the mask is all zero.  (i.e. check that every element is equal by checking that they aren't not-equal.)  That allows `kortest` on the mask itself.  I applied clang's idea to my intrinsics so GCC could make better asm as well.

In C++:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

// compare for not-equal, checking the mask for 0
bool check_contig(int *p)
{
    __m512i bcast_first = _mm512_set1_epi32(*p);
    __m512i desired = _mm512_add_epi32(bcast_first, _mm512_setr_epi32(15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0));

    __m512i v = _mm512_loadu_si512(p);
    __mmask16 cmp = _mm512_cmpneq_epi32_mask(desired, v);
    return cmp == 0;
}
```

[**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIArKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTFc8XaYDmlCBEzEBBk%2Bfly2mPZ5DDV1BAVhkdEg0gq19Y1ZLcPdvUUlgwCUtqhexMjsHOYAzMHI3lgA1CYbbngsLMEExMEAdAiH2CYaAIIPjwBunkyO9HvneykMAGtDlYngB6UF7NAsBJ1TB7fjEPYMVAEAC0mAAjl4xKRIQhKgDgsA9gR8XsWEwFAD4SQ9hoXhFUJ48QSAPpoQR4YAQX4AKgScxeJgA7CDHnsJXtWayWLEuGY8HsIqJhqyaMRhgcNgARKWnOVmVlKAhcVmYBJ4DZmCD8wUbMWSqUyg2KrApYiYdBa3Uy2Xy1lMdDoM0Wq0QZWUghqvAagi430Go2YC4hy3WsqkKSZjaZsyZlpcDSkACcpAAHKRhaQAGykeLSHN5loaOZ2sUvR3Sv0Kvavb167us2ioQNeI14A0QAXAjuSrsUqlcauQ6H9hP%2B5DQkIY1NWmWUgEQN0xz2415t2cS8F4Kh7CCbhLew66lt/YLU597LjAq8Qoh/TA4TQLBUWARgaURCJiEMZAECJPYBB%2BAhLz2D0CGWBgV0fZ9P3pe0hWFbUhSeYjHnBSFUGhWEIL2TFsVoXFYIJeDSThBdqSYYAmGCTUNFUKgBKoBkmVoFlkABdlZC5VlXi4HlBD2W0CIdOdnXlRUI1VdVNU/ddDWNU1zTTG1p3wp5OzUntjw9L1dP1f1A2DIyw00qNtLjAdE2NYhd3TeIsy4HN5XzTMi1LCsq1retSEbTNSBbC8SPM1Tu0VPs7MHYdR3HSdTJUiV5wPJcsLXezDQfTFfP3Kkj0wd1T17RLxUla9b3vVccJ1Ol%2BMEuY30Bftv3tX8SVQACgIwTBQPAhElWghhYPgxDCBQtCMJKzqXx6gSZxIwjSI4BZaE4WJeD8DgtFIVBODcaxrD%2BJYVjhTYeFIAhNEOhYARADYNiuX6AcBoHa2OjhJDOj6rs4XgFBAIt3ouw7SDgWAkChC16DICh70ojGBmAQK8xoWgCGiWHw0hiJgjqABPThXqp5hiBpgB5CJtEqBHXqhNhBBZhhaDpxHSCwCIvGANwxFoWHuF4LAKSMcRhfwD0qleOrIcwVRKi8Un6d4c42kh2g8Cg2mPCwSGLhOfWFioAxgAUAA1PBMAAdxZhJGH1mRBBEMR2CzfhBEUFR1GF3QWgMIwUDuyx9FN2HIAWVAEg6GXURZjY9lRCkVluHU8FWAwASmnZXYU1EAHUpd4VB1eIS43XgBYKiqZwIFcMZmlIQJgj6YoBhaHJUgEbvsmSUeGGmfpSladpqhGBpPCaPQ246Lp6hnwe58mUYV/GWwl%2B32YuFbx7VgkI6Toh4Xro4PZVDLatUWrSQ9mAZBkC/P6zDvXBCC0henMXgCMtCtlIPiQMAwIBfR%2Bn9IGiCAYg04ODUg51Lr3xhnDN6H0Fgo0QCgXGdBojkEoOjEhMQdiGAJsKDQLRiakw1JQCIlNqbMx9ozWmbMOYOB9jzRgBB%2BaC0hqLcWktaDSx9vLGhStLoq05ngdWMtLpax1nrWW5BBBG2FibM2zMLZrEutbFgts%2BAO2dq7D2XtzqvWDsIUQ4gg6yFDmoSGug8zR2MHHGweik6wKumnNIGcs45zzrBZ8Rc2hMFLqicugic410kXXBuTcNbJ3noojuXcD49z7oUWeE9chpHHsPSeHQT5D0ye3ToS9SnVI3sffuMwql72XpkHubTKmlHPssS%2BZ99A33QZDe%2Bj9n6v3ftQowX5hRXA0FcLg/98BEERMA0BeC4G/X%2BkgxBgywa30wdDWwOCwGfT2WYA5dcjmnIgQ3FIzhJBAA%3D%3D%3D) - asm from GCC and clang:

```
# GCC
check_contig(int*):
        vmovdqa32       zmm0, ZMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        vpaddd  zmm0, zmm0, DWORD PTR [rdi]{1to16}
        vpcmpd  k0, zmm0, ZMMWORD PTR [rdi], 4
        kortestw        k0, k0
        sete    al
        vzeroupper
        ret
```

```
# clang
check_contig(int*):
        vpbroadcastd    zmm0, dword ptr [rdi]
        vpaddd  zmm0, zmm0, zmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0]
        vpcmpneqd       k0, zmm0, zmmword ptr [rdi]
        kortestw        k0, k0
        sete    al
        vzeroupper
        ret
```

So they both choose to load twice instead of `vpbroadcastd zmm1, xmm0`, at least when not in a loop so the vector constant also has to get loaded from `.rodata`.

Perhaps if I wrote it differently, as `_mm512_broadcastd_epi32( _mm512_castsi512_si128(v))`, they'd prefer one load, at the cost of an extra shuffle uop.  (Which is probably worse when you have 512-bit uops in flight, so Intel CPUs shut down the vector ALU on port 1, leaving only ports 0 and 5.  https://agner.org/optimize/ and https://uops.info/)

---

#### Algo B - avoiding a non-trivial vector constant

Maybe your second way could also be done efficiently with `valignd` to rotate the vector; the only vector constant it needs is all-ones which can be generated somewhat more cheaply (`vpternlogd`) instead of loaded.

Checking the compare-mask would probably require a `kmov` to integer for an `and` + `cmp` to check all but one bit, unless we can use the same trick clang did and arrange things so we actually want the mask to be all-zero in the places we want.  In that case, `test eax, imm32` can check the bits we want while ignoring the one we don't.

Comment: Peter, I marked your answer as **the** answer. For those interested, I also posted (below) what I ended up doing (given my limited knowledge of SIMD). It seems mostly consistent with your suggestion. Also, it does speed up my benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

The core of my current Rust code is now this macro code:

```
    const LAST_INDEX: usize = <$simd>::lanes() - 1;
    let (expected, overflowed) = $chunk[0].overflowing_add(LAST_INDEX as $scalar);
    if overflowed || expected != $chunk[LAST_INDEX] {
        return false;
    }


    let a = unsafe { <$simd>::from_slice_aligned_unchecked($chunk) } + $decrease;
    let compare_mask = a.eq(<$simd>::splat(a.extract(0)));
    compare_mask.all()
```

Where $scalar is `u32`, $simd is `u32x16` and $decrease is the [15, 14 ... 0] block. The first part of the code spot checks that the last element is 15 more than the first (and takes care of overflows).

I asked a smart tool to help me understand the SIMD assembly produced. It says:

> - vmovdqa64:
>   This instruction moves a 512-bit vector of data into a ZMM register.
>   It's used here twice: vmovdqa64 zmm0,zmmword ptr [...]: Loads a
>   512-bit vector from memory into zmm0. vmovdqa64 zmm0,zmmword ptr [...]
>   (later in the code): Loads a different 512-bit vector into zmm0.
>   vpaddd:
> - vpaddd zmm0,zmm0,zmmword ptr [rax+40h]: Performs packed integer
>   addition of 32-bit integers. This instruction adds the 512-bit vector
>   in zmm0 to another 512-bit vector (loaded from the memory address in
>   rax + 40h) and stores the result back in zmm0. vpbroadcastd:
> - vpbroadcastd zmm1,xmm0: Broadcasts a 32-bit integer from xmm0 (lower
>   128 bits of zmm0) across all lanes of zmm1. This creates a 512-bit
>   vector in zmm1 where all elements are the same and equal to the value
>   in xmm0. vpcmpeqd:
> - vpcmpeqd k0,zmm0,zmm1: Compares 32-bit integers in zmm0 and zmm1 for
>   equality. The results are stored in a mask register k0, where each bit
>   represents the result of the comparison for each pair of elements.
>   vpternlogd:
> - vpternlogd zmm1,zmm1,zmm1,0FFh: Performs a bitwise ternary logic
>   operation on each bit of the operands. The specific operation is
>   determined by the immediate value 0xFF, which in this case corresponds
>   to a bitwise OR. vpmovm2d:
> - vpmovm2d zmm0,k0: Moves the bitmask from the mask register k0 into a
>   general-purpose register zmm0. Each bit of k0 becomes a 32-bit element
>   in zmm0. vpcmpd:
> - vpcmpd k0,zmm0,zmm1,4: Compares 32-bit integers in zmm0 and zmm1
>   according to the predicate provided as the last operand (here 4, which
>   typically represents "less than"). The result is stored in the mask
>   register k0. vmovdqu64:
> - vmovdqu64 zmmword ptr [rsp+50h],zmm0: Moves the 512-bit vector in zmm0
>   into memory at the address rsp + 50h. kortestw:
> - kortestw k0,k0: Tests the contents of the mask register k0 and sets
>   the zero flag based on the result. This is often used for conditional
>   branches based on SIMD comparison results.
> - vzeroupper:
>   This instruction is used to clear the upper 256 bits of all YMM
>   registers to avoid penalties when mixing AVX-512 and legacy SSE code.
>   It's a good practice to use this instruction before calls to functions
>   that might not be AVX-512 aware.

Comment: `vpternlogd z,z,z, 0xff` isn't a bitwise OR.  It produces all-ones in the output since all 8 bits of the truth-table are `1`.  i.e. it's how compilers implement `_mm512_set1_epi32(-1)`.  Yikes, did `compare_mask.all()` compile into turning the mask back into a vector for a compare?  That's terrible. Like I explained in my answer, at worst just `kmovw eax, k0` to a general-purpose register for `cmp eax, 0xffff` (or `cmp ax, -1` like GCC used.)  At best, do the opposite of `.eq` so you just need to check the mask for all-zero instead of all-one, something you can do directly with `kortestw`

Comment: (You probably can't fix the code-gen for `compare_mask.all()`, that's up to the compiler.  But you can change the source to use an `ne` instead of `eq` comparison like I did after looking at clang's asm output; see the two versions in my Godbolt link.)  Also, your compiler is doing `vmovdqu64 [rsp+50h],zmm0`?  Are you later printing the vector or something?  It shouldn't need to save that vector on the stack for later.

Comment: Also, is the scalar early-out common?  If not, I might only do a scalar check for being within 15 of u32 wrap-around, if you don't want to count `0xffffffff` as contiguous with `0`.  (i.e. `cmp dword [rdi], 0 - 15` / `jae would_wrap`).  Let the SIMD work rule out sequences that aren't contiguous.  But if the surrounding code (or other hyper-thread) has a lot of 512-bit uops, and an early-out is commonly taken, then it could be worth branching on that.  Benchmark both ways for your real use-case on a few CPUs like Ice Lake and Zen 4 to see how branch-prediction and out-of-order exec handle it.

Comment: @PeterCordes, if you (or anyone) is curious the full disassembly is here:
https://github.com/CarlKCarlK/range-set-blaze/tree/77583275dc6d68f5c4e1f06aaaf32187b6c10923/examples
as simdtest.asm.txt (the Rust source is simdtest.rs).

Benchmarking (not shown), SIMD makes things about 3 times faster (604.17 µs vs 185.79 µs)

On the question of early exit, on my distribution of data, it seems to make things just a little bit faster. (without it 206.02 µs)

I tried switching from ".eq/.all"  to ".ne/.any/!" but the speed stayed the same (186.10 µs)

I'm content for now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://rust.godbolt.org/ is a good tool for seeing how things compile.  I'm surprised `.ne` doesn't help; maybe the compiler does a bad job there, or uop throughput isn't the bottleneck.  Or the compiler does a bad job for that as well.  If there's a missed-optimization worth reporting upstream to Rust or LLVM, it would be good to know.

Comment: Correction: On the benchmark, SIMD was twice as fast 414.30 µs vs 185.79 µs (not 3 times faster).

goldbolt.org would be a good. I tried but couldn't figure out dependances. lazy_static is there (but I couldn't get it working). I couldn't find packed_simd.
https://rust.godbolt.org/z/4hra7MW68